# hasManyThrough - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have database table structure like :

ClassRoom

- id (int) **PK**
- name (varchar)

ClassTeacherCourse

- id (int) **PK**
- id_classroom (int) **FK**
- id_teacher (int) **FK**
- id_course (int) **FK**

Course

- id (int) **PK**
- course_name (varchar)

Teacher

- id (int) **PK**
- teacher_name (varchar)

So far I have code just to call ClassRoom table & ClassTeacherCourse, like :

```
$class = Class::find($id)
                 ->with(['classcourseteacher'])
                 ->get();
```

Relationship in `Class` Model :

```
public function classcourseteacher() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ClassCourseTeacher', 'id_class', 'id');
}
```

Result :

```
[
    {
        "id": 57,
        "id_school": 2,
        "class_name": "7 I",
        "classcourseteacher": [
            {
                "id": 406,
                "id_class": 57,
                "id_course": 9,
                "id_teacher": 68,
                "created_at": "2020-11-10 16:11:14",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-10 16:11:14"
            },
            {
                "id": 434,
                "id_class": 57,
                "id_course": 11,
                "id_teacher": 66,
                "created_at": "2020-11-10 16:11:14",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-10 16:11:14"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I have read [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) about `hasManyThrough` but in docs different case with me.

How to call in 1 time via Eloquent: Relationship with Course & Teacher details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `ClassTeacherCourse` class put the teacher and course relation

```
function teacher() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
}

function course() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

and then u can call it like this to get the detail

```
$class = Class::find($id)
             ->with(['classcourseteacher.teacher', 'classcourseteacher.course'])
             ->get();
```